# sed to match multiple lines, but only after a certain line has been seen

Tags: sed

I'm trying to do some very simple rss parsing with sed. Like plucking out enclosure urls for listening to the latest news.
Example:

```
sed -n -e 's/.*"\([^"]*\.mp3\)".*/\1/p' -e 's/.*<title>\([^<]*\)<.title>.*/\1/p'
```

Though, what I would like to do is to start this matching only after a certain token has been seen, in this case "<item>", so that I don't catch any feed <title>s, or such.

GNU sed is fine, and I think I could somehow use the two-address form '0,/REGEXP/' but I don't know how to combine this to achieve the above

Added for Dawnofthedead:

```
foo
bar
baz
<title>fum</title>
baz
fie
<item>
  <title>1</title>
  <enclosure url="one.mp3">
</item>
<item>
  <title>2</title>
  <enclosure url="two.mp3">
</item>
```

should give me

```
1
one.mp3
2
two.mp3
```

Answer (score 2):

if you would stick to sed, try this line. this line works with given example:

```
kent$  sed -nr '/<item>/,/<\/item>/p' yourFile|sed -nr '/<title>/{s#[ ]*<[/]?title>##g;p}; /<enclosure/{ s#.*url="(.*)">#\1#g;p}'
```

**test**

```
kent$  cat t
foo
bar
baz
<title>fum</title>
baz
fie
<item>
  <title>1</title>
  <enclosure url="one.mp3">
</item>
<item>
  <title>2</title>
  <enclosure url="two.mp3">
</item>

kent$  sed -nr '/<item>/,/<\/item>/p' t |sed -nr '/<title>/{s#[ ]*<[/]?title>##g;p}; /<enclosure/{ s#.*url="(.*)">#\1#g;p}'
1
one.mp3
2
two.mp3
```

Comment: Thanks Kent, I was stuck at trying to combine the, but two sed's is fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ sed -n -f s.sed input
1
one.mp3
2
two.mp3
```

where s.sed is:

```
/<item>/,/<\/item>/{
    s/^.*>\([^<]\+\).*$/\1/
    s/^.*"\(.*\)".*$/\1/
    />$/d
    p
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to parse a simple XML (like an RSS feed) in command line why don't you try **xsltproc** ?

It takes in input an xml and can apply an xslt transformation stylesheet. 
You have to learn the xslt language but you can produce better output.

Comment: I'd rather learn how to match/replace with sed only after a certain match has been made. In the past I have used combinations of awk and sed. But I though sed should be enough somehow. This is something I find myself wanting to do for different kinds of files, not only xml.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
sed '$!N;s/^\s*<title>\(.*\)<\/title>\n\s*<enclosure url="\([^"]*\)">/\1\n\2/p;D' file
1
one.mp3
2
two.mp3
```

Rather than look between `<item>...</item>`s look for the two lines `<title>...<enclosure...`